# Lucene takes around 5 minutes to index 14million documents - any way to optimize it?

Tags: kotlin, lucene

I have a file containing 14 million records each with 2 fields. I had indexed the documents with below config:

```
private fun getIndexWriter(directory: String): IndexWriter = try {
        val indexWriterConfig = IndexWriterConfig(KeywordAnalyzer())
        indexWriterConfig.ramBufferSizeMB = 2048.0
        indexWriterConfig.openMode = IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND
        IndexWriter(FSDirectory.open(Paths.get(directory)), indexWriterConfig)
    } catch (exception: Exception) {
        logger.error("File missing: {} ", exception.message)
        throw Exception("File missing: ${exception.message}")
    }


fun indexDocs(documents: List<Document>)= mutex.withLock {
        coroutineScope {
            val indexedDocs = getIndexWriter("directory_path").use { indexWriter ->
                try {
                    documents.forEach { document ->
                        try {
                            indexWriter.addDocument(document)
                        } catch (exception: IOException) {
                            logger.error("Failed to add document: {} to passive index", document)
                        }
                    }
                    indexWriter.flush()
                    indexWriter.commit()
                } catch (exception: IOException) {
                    logger.error("Failed to commit")
                }
                indexWriter.docStats.numDocs
            }
        }
    }
```

It takes 5 minutes around to complete the index and to start the application, however I wanted to check if there can be some optimization done to reduce the time taken for indexing.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: You only need to build the index once, right? Not every time you start your app. After the initial build, can the index can be maintained with inserts, updates and deletes?

Comment: Thats right, I need to do in that way, but still to build the index it takes around 5 minutes. So, I want to check if the above code can be optimized because I foressee the records count can increase in future to 100million.

Comment: I definitely understand that you prefer it to be faster (that is reasonable) - but why does it matter if it takes 5 or 10 minutes, or 1 hour, if you only need to do it once? Is there some specific problem that would cause?

Comment: You can certainly experiment with increasing the RAM buffer more - and also maybe increasing the JVM's startup value for `-Xmx`. You can flush and commit less frequently - maybe even once at the end (not sure if that will make a tangible difference). Have you taken a look at [`WriteLineDocTask`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/9_3_0/benchmark/org/apache/lucene/benchmark/byTask/tasks/WriteLineDocTask.html), where you can place multiple docs in one file, and index them all at once? Doing that should be more efficient than processing "one-doc-per-file".